# Using java - using if else statement in a switch?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm pretty new to Java, and coding in general. In my class we need the user to input the month (1-12) and a day (1-30) and we determine on a set date (june 15 to sept 30th) if it is or is not monsoon season. I'm trying to use a if else statement in a switch to say that anytime before june 15 is not monsoon season but my code keeps showing both if and else statement. Any help is welcomed, thank you!

```
import java.util.*;

public class Monsoon

 {  public static void main (String[]args)
    {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);



    // Prompt the user to enter month & Day
    System.out.print("Please enter a month(1-12) and day (1-31): " );
    int month = kb.nextInt();
    int day = kb.nextInt();


    // using a switch statement to show months
    switch (month){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("is NOT monsoon season");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("is NOT monsoon season");
            break;
        case 3:
        System.out.println("is NOT monsoon season");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("is NOT monsoon season");
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("is NOT monsoon season");
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("“is monsoon season");

            // use if else statement so user knows that before june 15 is not monsoon season
        if (day>=15)
            System.out.print("it is monsoon season");
        else
            System.out.print("it is not monsoon season");


            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("“is monsoon season");
            break;
        case 8:
            System.out.println("“is monsoon season");
            break;
        case 9:
            System.out.println("“is monsoon season");
            break;
        case 10:
            System.out.println("is NOT monsoon season");
            break;
        case 11:
            System.out.println("is NOT monsoon season");
            break;
        case 12:
            System.out.println("is NOT monsoon season");
            break;

        default: System.out.println("not valid");
        break;

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Well you *unconditionally* print "is monsoon season" before you print "it is monsoon season" or "it is not monsoon season".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repetition is bad. You can do it like this, utilizing the [fall-through](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) feature of the switch-case:

```
boolean isMonsoon;

switch (month) {
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
        isMonsoon = true;
        break;

    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 10:
    case 11:
    case 12:
        isMonsoon = false;
        break;

    case 6:
        // use if else statement so user knows that before june 15 is not monsoon season
        if (day >= 15)
            isMonsoon = true;
        else
            isMonsoon = false;
        break;

    default:
        System.out.println("not valid");
        break;
}

if (isMonsoon)
    System.out.println("is monsoon season");
else
    System.out.println("is NOT monsoon season");
```

Or, since the monsoon season is a *range*, using comparison operators is probably more suitable than a switch-case:

```
if ((month >= 7 && month < 10) || (month == 6 && day >= 15))
    System.out.println("is monsoon season");
else
    System.out.println("is NOT monsoon season");
```

Comment: For beginner learning's sake, what's happening here is that having multiple cases in a row without having `break` to separate them causes the program to keep running through all cases until it hits a break (or the end of the switch). This is called "falling through" cases.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me, I appreciate the follow through :)